# calculate time taken to reach from network A to B without ping and telnet

Tags: networking, linux, packet

I want to find distance between A and B either in terms of network time or Hops count.I have few ideas like I can ping B from A will log down time taken to respond that ping request . Also If I know any port open on B then I can simply do telnet to that port and will capture time taken by journey of request.

But my concern is if B will not share any open port or Blocks ping request as well. In absence of reply back option how I will make sure that how much time A will take to reach B .

May be I am doing something very stupid . But I am very keen to know if there is any mechanism/protocol to do such calculation . As I can imagine lets say if B is dropping all probes But one thing becomes clear that at-least packet is reaching to B or may be somewhere near to B .I just want that one way time where packet traversed till B or its nearby before getting refused or timeout.

Any help/idea for the same will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If B silently drops packets, then there's no way to know where B is (or even if there is a B).
The best you could do is do a traceroute to B and use the last hop as an approximate location/distance.

Comment: Thanks Ron , Yes actually could be helpful and can give  good idea of distance but it is very slow to trace. I was looking something faster.

Comment: Do a traceroute to find the last hop, then ping the last hop. Slow at first, then fast. If that is still too 'slow', can we ask why speed is important? Or is it just impatience?